# What Java XML API to use in my app - StAX or DOM?

Tags: java, xml, dom, stax

I did some research, looked at the table at the bottom here (1) and I am trying to find out what kind of API I should use.

Let me introduce the problem my app in going to solve:

My application listens to some observer events fired from all places (e.g. events from CDI) in some observer class. In that class, there are methods which observes these events.

I need to construct XML file on-the-fly as these events are being observed. More concretely, when I observe event "start", I need to create this xml.

```
<start></start>
```

After that when I observe some other event, like "installed" (does not matter how it is called really), I need to have this structure:

```
<start><installed></installed><start>
```

Everytime I observe some event, I need to be able to write that XML representation to external file. Summing it up, it seems I can not use "SAX" because SAX just parses XML documents but I need to write them or construct them. Next, I am about to use StAX or DOM but StAX is "forward only" which I do not quite understand what it stands for, but when I take StAX API it behaves like this (2) and when it is "forward" I am "forced" to manually start and end elements but that is not applicable in my case. I do not know when I am about to end the document generation, I just need to have valid xml every time in order to write it.

However, there is this method (3) which says that when I call it, it automatically closes all elements. So e.g. when I have this:

```
<a>
    <b></b>
    <c>
        <d>
        </d>
```

and I call writeEndDocument(), does that mean that it automatically closes "c" and "a"?

(1) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/SJSXP2.html

(2) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/example.html#bnbgx

(3) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html#writeEndDocument()

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the following XML libraries (ordered by recommendation; only use the next one if the one before doesn't suit you needs):

1. JAXB (work with objects rather than XML)
2. StAX (lower level than JAXB)
3. SAX (only for reading; should be rarely used now with JAXB and StAX available)
4. DOM (should be rarely used now with JAXB and StAX available)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use lower level XML techniques (either SAX or DOM) unless you really need them. I believe that this is not the case.

Use JAXB. Create class that represents your events. Every time you get event create instance of this class and populate fields. Every time you have to create XML just marshal the instance(s) to any stream you want (file, socket, whatever).

Comment: The problem is that it would be some kind of reporter application where anybody can fire his own event which will be marshalled to XML so I do not know in advance every object which would be reported. That means user would have to provide JAXB view of class being reported. I would rather somehow forward the handler in which user marshalls his object as he wants.

Comment: Well, I think it is not so bad idea. User can just implement his view of object he wants to report and send that object in event my observer would observe and it would be added to the structure.